# Was "Star Wars: The Force Awakens - A Junior Novel" based on the film's script or the official novelisation?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

Star Wars has received two novelisations, one by Alan Dean Foster (generally described as the "[official novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(novel))" and a second "*Junior*" novelisation by Michael Kogge which was released several days after the film (entitled [Star Wars: The Force Awakens - A Junior novel](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(junior_novelization))).

**Was the "Junior" novel based on the screenplay, the film or the official novelisation?**

[image]

Comment: So what will be in the junior version? It's already pg-13 movie. We talking [Ewoks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tLt0GaIBMIs)??

Comment: @Daft - The junior version is actually pretty similar to the adult novelisation, just with slightly simpler language. - **Adult Version:** *Below, Han had finished setting a charge and was preparing to climb a bit higher to place one more when a sound made him hesitate. The working structure was full of unidentifiable sounds, but this was different. Taking no chances, he slipped behind a wide vertical support. Either the sound would not be repeated, or…
A glance around the edge of his cover revealed its source, and his countenance underwent a grave shift."*

Comment: **Junior version** "*Han stuck the explosive charges around the base of the pillar and programmed each to detonate by remote activation. About to plant his final charge, he heard a clank. Han ducked behind a support beam and waited before he chanced a look. His son peered down from a catwalk."*

Comment: Apparently [h8rs still gotta h8](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: It's still enriching the site with information, some people -.-

Comment: @JohnBell - Certain users have accused me of "*questionable form*" for answering my own questions. Apparently this upsets them in some way.

Comment: _"With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about science fiction or fantasy."_ - **Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange About Page**. Maybe they are just bottom-struck ;)

Comment: @johnbell - Given that I'd actually spoken (well, twittered) the author, a self-answered question seemed the ideal way to share this *completely new* knowledge.

Comment: why is the blast emmiter on Starkiller dark? [Every other version](http://a.dilcdn.com/bl/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2015/10/star-wars-force-awakens-official-poster.jpg) of the cover  shows it being orange.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I took the liberty of [asking](https://twitter.com/michaelkogge/status/683684813715341312) my good friend Michael Kogge this question. He was kind enough to provide me with a response:

> **Q:**   *Wondering if your Star Wars Junior novel was based on the ADF novelization or your own reading of the Kasdan script?*
>
> **Kogge:** *[I] used both as resources!*